# Python Import: import multiple modules in one file

Tags: python

I have many frequently used modules such as `os, cv2, numpy,`... Every time I need to import them at the beginning of each python file. Now I want to write the `import` code into one file named `all_import.py`, and for each python file only import `all_import` to import all the modules I need.

Is that possible to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible (but really should not be done).  Just set up your files like so:

> b.py

```
import numpy
import scipy
```

> a.py

```
from b import *
```

And then use whatever you imported in `b.py`

Comment: Thanks for this answer. But is it possible to avoid using `import *`? I am afraid `import *` will cause other naming problem.

Comment: @C.Wang You should not be doing this to begin with.

Comment: I don't understand, do you mean I run the line `from b import *` at the end of a python file?

Comment: @C.Wang No, I mean: don't do this.  Just import your modules the way you mention at the beginning of your question.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!

Comment: @C.Wang I know it can be tempting to want to avoid long lists of imports, but most IDE's will let you minimize them to avoid clutter, and overall it is a better approach.

Answer (score 3):

It is not recommended to do such thing but theoretically it is doable.

`all_import.py`:

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy

__all__ = ['os', 'cv2', 'numpy']
```

`other_script.py`:

```
import all_import as ai

# use `os`
ai.os.system('echo "Hello!"')
```

Comparing to @chrisz's answer, this one doesn't violate any [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) format.

Comment: @JacquesGaudin To conform to PEP8.

Answer (score 1):

create a folder as python package

```
my_fodler
```

inside it, create an `__init__.py` file, where you add all your imports.

```
import os
import subprocess
```

go back to the same path as `my_folder` and create your file, and there you call your package like:

```
from my_folder import *
```

Here is how it would look like:

----|>`my_folder`

----|----> `__init__.py`

----|>`your_file.py`