# Python master import file

Tags: python, import, module, package, libraries

I have several scripts in a project folder, most of which use the same handful of standard libraries and modules.  Instead of having to reiterate in every single script

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
import re
etc
etc
```

is it possible for me to place all `import` statements in a `masterImports.py` file and simply `import masterImports` at the top of each script ?

Comment: Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49657845/python-import-import-multiple-modules-in-one-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

So the basic idea is to import all the libraries in one file. Then import that file.

An example:

**masterImports.py**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
import re
etc
etc
```

**otherFile.py**

```
import masterImports as mi
print(mi.datetime.datetime(2021,7,20))
```

Or you could use wildcard imports -

```
from masterImports import * # OR from masterImports import important_package
print(datetime.datetime(2021,7,20))
```

Do not use wildcard asterix imports because there can be name clashes

Try this, and you will see that there is no error

Comment: Thanks, @PCM.  However, can you please clarify your comments at the end of your post.  You propose ```import * ``` as a solution, then proceed to say that it can cause problems, then say that it will cause no error.  Based on another small test I ran, the wildcard import is giving me the desired result (importing into file2 all that was initially imported in file1), but I am failing to see what you are cautioning me about.

Comment: Well yeah, sometimes it can be useful. But as I said, it is better to use it carefully see [why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615125/should-wildcard-import-be-avoided). I was only telling you to be cautious. Name clashes mean when you are importing any file it might overwrite in-built or user-built functions. So, I said it is better to avoid that.

Comment: If my answer helps you, kindly accept it.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, although not really the done thing

To use it, you'd need to do, at the top of each script:

```
from master_imports import *
```